# Partial eigendecomposition of a positive semi-definite matrix

Tags: matrices, matrix-decomposition, positive-semidefinite, unitary-matrices

Any positive semi-definite matrix $A$ can be decomposed into
$$
  A = Q \Lambda Q^\dagger,
$$
where $Q$ is a unitary matrix and $\Lambda$ is a diagonal matrix.
Now I would assume that there is a  partial decomposition as well, where
$$
  A = U X U^\dagger,
$$
where $U$ is a different unitary matrix and the matrix
$$
  X = \begin{bmatrix}
    D & 0 \\
    0 & B \\
  \end{bmatrix},
$$
consists of a diagonal block $D$ and a block $B$.

Does such a decomposition exist? If yes, does it have a particular name? Also, (if yes) what algorithm can be used to produce such a decomposition?

Comment: Sure. In $Q$, keep the first $k$ column vectors and mix up the rest. Never heard of a name for it.

Comment: @Chrystomath Thanks for your comment. Any recommendations for the algorithm?

Comment: The one that springs to mind is: Start with the standard basis; find $k$ eigenvectors and perform Gram-Schmidt on the rest of the basis. But this takes as long as finding all the eigenvectors at one go, I think. Btw, I should have said "rotate the rest", not "mix up the rest". Mixing the columns simply permutes the eigenvalues.

Comment: I think it is the same question as this one:
https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/33068/partially-diagonalizing-a-matrix
I do not know a name, though.